# Python - Display debug output to console via a command-line option

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, logging, command-line, console

Let's say I have a file named main.py.  I want to output a debug message to console via command line. I want to be able to do something like this...

```
python2.7 -someOption main.py
```

Where it will spit out a debug message to console.  I've looked a '-d' flag and PYTHONDEBUG environment variable and have had no success.

Sample code below:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug("sup")
```